# If the docker updates its linux kernel, does it break the existing docker images?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, operating-system, docker-machine

I am very new to docker. I have installed docker desktop on my mac. When i execute `docker version` it is showing `OS/Arch:linux/amd64` under server docker engine. I am assuming this means that docker installed linux kernel on top of my mac OS using hypervisor to manage linux based containers. if this linux kernel got updated, will it going break the functionalities of existing images?

Why am I asking this question?

Recently after updating my mac OS to 10.15.2, things started breaking because of openssl and ruby-2.3.x compatibility issues. And I was told, we could solve these type of issues using docker since it is independent of host OS?

But docker itself has own linux kernel, Will i be going to face this issue if linux kernel got updated?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got those errors because you were depending software libraries available on the machine. They are not related to kernel. Any such software dependencies should be bundled with the docker image. Linux kernel upgrades never break user space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So since OS and other software programs is also bundled with the image itself, there wont be the problem.Problem happens when bundled OS version is changed i suppose @shashank v